# Change MongoDB document IDs as soon as converting a replica set to shared cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I was wondering, if the unique document IDs changes as soon as I'm moving a database from a single machine to a shared cluster? I'm asking because I read, that mongoDB builds the ID based on the server, time, etc..

I read this [tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/) and now I'm not sure, if I have to implement my own "unique id" to make sure, the ID is always the same.

I'm happy about any tip!

Thank you

Comment: No, the id doesn't change on such migration. In fact, you can't change a document's id at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the IDs stay the same. The ID is generated when you first create the document and then it stays the same. The server and time components of the ID are just to ensure that the ID is unique.